# Using Task State Segment to handle ring 0 int

Tags: c, exception, x86, kernel, low-level

I've been working from some time on easy os kernel. So far I've properly setup IDT with one INT (software).
Next step was to try to get to ring 3 of kernel. This was dane by  me using 'trick' with `iret` ring switch was successful, as 
state of segment register indicate. Problems occurred when I tried to use `int $20` to switch to ring 0 to handle this interrupt.
Of course I have setup TSS to be able to do such action. Here is some code:
This function encodes descriptor (I've enclosed this because I think this can be problem with encoding)

```
    void register_descriptor(unsigned entryIdx, uint32_t base, uint32_t limit, uint16_t flag)
    {
        uint64_t descriptor;
        descriptor  =  limit       & 0x000F0000;         
        descriptor |= (flag <<  8) & 0x00F0FF00;         
        descriptor |= (base >> 16) & 0x000000FF;         
        descriptor |=  base        & 0xFF000000;         
        descriptor <<= 32;
        descriptor |= base  << 16;                       
        descriptor |= limit  & 0x0000FFFF;               
        GDT[entryIdx] = descriptor;
    }
```

TSS loading to GDT (`zeroTSS()` just set all members of TSS struct to 0):

```
static void write_tss(unsigned num, uint16_t ss0, uint32_t esp0)
{
   register_descriptor(num, (uint32_t) &tss_entry, sizeof(tss_entry), (TSS));
   zeroTSS();

   tss_entry.ss0  = ss0; 
   tss_entry.esp0 = esp0;

   tss_entry.cs   = 0x18;
   tss_entry.ss = tss_entry.ds = tss_entry.es = tss_entry.fs = tss_entry.gs = 0x20;
}
```

TSS Flush(My GDT have 6 entries (NULL+TSS+4 Segment)):

```
    .global flush_tss
    flush_tss:
        mov $0x28, %ax
        ltr %ax
    ret
```

And interupt handler register:

```
    IDTEntry fillIDTEntry(uint32_t intHandler,
                          uint16_t selector,   
                          uint8_t type_attr)

    {   IDTEntry newEntry;
        newEntry.offset_low = LOW_FUN_ADDR(intHandler); 
        newEntry.selector = selector; 
        newEntry.zero = 0;     
        newEntry.type_attr = type_attr;
        newEntry.offset_up = UP_FUN_ADDR(intHandler);
        return newEntry;
    }

    extern void _lidt(_IDT_PTR* idtPtr);
    void loadIDT()
    {
        zeroIDT();
        _IDT_PTR idtPtr;
        idtPtr.idtSize = sizeof(struct __InteruptDescriptorTableEntry)*256 - 1;
        idtPtr.idtBaseAddr = (uint32_t) &InteruptDescriptorTable;

        IDTEntry printOnScreenInt = fillIDTEntry((uint32_t)interupt_pritnOnScreen, 0x18, 0x8e);
        registerInterupt(printOnScreenInt, 32);
        _lidt(&idtPtr);
    }

    .global _lidt
    _lidt:
        push %ebp
        mov %esp,%ebp

        mov 8(%esp), %eax
        lidt (%eax)
    leave
    ret
```

Finally print form Bochs:

```
    [CPU0  ] interrupt(): soft_int && (gate.dpl < CPL)
    [CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x0d)
    [CPU0  ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x08)
    [CPU0  ] CPU is in protected mode (active)
    [CPU0  ] CS.mode = 32 bit
    [CPU0  ] SS.mode = 32 bit
    [CPU0  ] EFER   = 0x00000000
    [CPU0  ] | EAX=00100d48  EBX=001058b4  ECX=00000720  EDX=001058c2
    [CPU0  ] | ESP=0010589c  EBP=0010589c  ESI=00101000  EDI=00000000
    [CPU0  ] | IOPL=0 ID vip vif ac vm RF nt of df if tf sf zf af PF cf
    [CPU0  ] | SEG sltr(index|ti|rpl)     base    limit G D
    [CPU0  ] |  CS:000b( 0001| 0|  3) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
    [CPU0  ] |  DS:0013( 0002| 0|  3) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
    [CPU0  ] |  SS:0013( 0002| 0|  3) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
    [CPU0  ] |  ES:0013( 0002| 0|  3) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
    [CPU0  ] |  FS:0013( 0002| 0|  3) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
    [CPU0  ] |  GS:0013( 0002| 0|  3) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
    [CPU0  ] | EIP=001008ed (001008ed)
    [CPU0  ] | CR0=0x60000011 CR2=0x00000000
    [CPU0  ] | CR3=0x00000000 CR4=0x00000000
    [CPU0  ] 0x001008ed>> int 0x20 : CD20
```

I will only mention that before introducing two privilege levels this interrupt handler was working.

Comment: The DPL of the `0x20` IDT entry needs to be bigger or equal to the CPL in order to not have an exception.

Comment: really, that's it? :)

Comment: Yes, I'm still a bit confused with this cpl/dpl/rpl mechanics. Now I am stuck at passing parameters to interrupt :)

Comment: Ok, make an edit. We'll have a look.